# How can i get a specific cell in update method of javafx table view?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

[image]I want set the the graphics of starting cell to an eror image when there is any error in the table view data(any row data).I am using the following code inside the update method.

```
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

          super.updateItem(item, empty);
          String text = getString();
          setText(empty ? null : text);
          String text2 = text.trim();

          boolean isHex = text2.matches("^[0-9A-Fa-fx]+$");
          // Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("^[0-9A-Fa-fx]+.*");
          // Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(text);
          // boolean find = matcher.find();
          // getTableView().getColumns().;
          setGraphic(null);
          if (!isHex) {
            getStyleClass().add("oneCell");

            // this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
            // getTableView().getColumns().get(0;
            revertbackchanges();
            Image error = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("twobuttons/icon_error_1.png"));

          } else {
            setGraphic(null);
            getStyleClass().remove("oneCell");
          }
```

here i am checking the cell data whether the data are hex value or not if other than hex is entered then i am changing the color of the cell to red .Now i want to show a error like icon on the 1st cell .How can i get the 1st cell from table view and set the graphics on it.As shown on image i can show an error with respective to cell on which user has entered the wrong value but along with that i want to show and error icon on Command cell i.e TX_default or i want to highlight the whole cell .Any help on this is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this time its workied i tired..

```
Image img  =new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Add-Male-User-icon.png"));
    ImageView imgs  =new ImageView(img);
tablecol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<CheckDo, String>, TableCell<CheckDo, String>>() {

    @Override
    public TableCell<CheckDo, String> call(TableColumn<CheckDo, String> p) {


         return new TableCell<CheckDo, String>() {

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!isEmpty())
               this.setGraphic(imgs);
            }
        }
    };
```

[image]

Comment: i could able to do that but along with it i want to set the graphics of 1st table view cell .Like some error icon

Comment: @Rajesh use the same way but only change is that give you first column name like "userid" and the fire listner...after fire it break it at last means use it only once

Comment: @Rajesh now i am edit above answer and its perfectly worked...i hope now you get

Comment: ImageView is necessary for set image...image() just provide set image resource

Comment: thanks for  your support . I Could able to put color and graphics on the cell on which user is editing. But my requirement is to put a color or some error  graphics on the table 1st cell . I have edited my query with an image please have a look at it.

Comment: @Rajesh runtime it is not possible you can set particular cell property...you have to set muiltiple object observation lise.you have to set this at observationlist() time...where you set your table..

try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067481/javafx-2-tableview-different-cell-factory-depending-on-the-data-inside-the-cel ...here you can get the solutions...if you like my answer vote it up :)

Comment: @thanks anshul now i am  thinking give the error icon on same cell and using setgraphics i can do that but can i replicate the same thing using the css.Any pointer on this will help me

Comment: @Rajesh css for table is too much big...i cant not give it here...you ask new question "style of table" and give me here the link of question and there i give you default css of table :)