# Using a button in a tableColumn to add a song to a playlist javafx

Tags: javafx, tablecolumn

I was want have a table column with a button labeled "Add to Playlist". The row in the column represents a song. I have the following class:

```
private class ButtonCell extends TableCell<Record, Boolean> {
    final Button cellButton = new Button("Add to PlayList");

    ButtonCell(){

        cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                // do something when button clicked
                //playList.add(this.getTableRow().getItem());
            }
        });
    }

    //Display button if the row is not empty
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(t, empty);
        if(!empty){
            setGraphic(cellButton);
        }
    }
}

EventHandler<ActionEvent> btnNewHandler = 
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {


    }
};
```

And I want to be able to do this 'playList.add(this.getTableRow().getItem());'
Is there a way to do this?

The gist of the question is how do I get the information of a cell and add that information to an observable list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, [`getTableRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html#getTableRow--) returns a raw `TableRow` object, instead of a generically typed one. In other words the method signature is

```
public class TableCell<S,T> {
    public TableRow getTableRow();
}
```

when I think it should be

```
public class TableCell<S,T> {
    public TableRow<S> getTableRow();
}
```

Because of this, the expresison `getTableRow().getItem()` has a compile-time type of `Object`, instead of the same type as the table (`Record` in your example), so you need a downcast. This should work (assuming you have everything else set up as I expect you do):

```
playList.add((Record) this.getTableRow().getItem() );
```

A different technique entirely is to make the column type `Record`, so you can just call `getItem()` directly on the cell. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925697/display-image-on-tableview-when-object-is-of-a-type/27929338#27929338) uses this approach.

Comment: ha i keep solving some of my own issues, but I don't know how to solve the following:
'error: no suitable method found for add(Object)
                    MusicPlayer.playlist.add(getTableRow().getItem() );
                                        ^
    method Collection.add(Song) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Song)
    method List.add(Song) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Song)'