# TableColumn should only show one specific value of a complex data type

Tags: java, javafx, tablecolumn

**You can find the answer at the original question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137182/4469105**

I need a `JavaFX TableColumn` to show only one specific value of a complex data type (`Issue.class`).
Here is a bit of my code:

Issue.class

```
public class Issue {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Issue> dependencies;

    //Getter
    ....
}
```

TableView.class

```
public TableView createIssueTable() {

    TableColumn<Issue, String> firstCol = new TableColumn<>("ID");
    TableColumn<Issue, String> secondCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    TableColumn<Issue, List<Issue>> thirdCol = new TableColumn<>(
            "Dependencies");

    PropertyValueFactory<Issue, String> firstColFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>(
            "id");
    PropertyValueFactory<Issue, String> secondColFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>(
            "name");
    PropertyValueFactory<Issue, List<Issue>> thirdColFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>(
            "dependencies");

    firstCol.setCellValueFactory(firstColFactory);
    secondCol.setCellValueFactory(secondColFactory);
    thirdCol.setCellValueFactory(thirdColFactory);

    myTableview.getColumns().addAll(....);
    return myTableview;
}
```

When I populate the table with data the 3rd column (`<Issue, List<Issue>>`) shows something like `[Issue [i1, issuee01, ...] [...]]`.
I want the 3rd column to show only the `id` of the `Issue`.
I messed around with `setCellValueFactory(...)` but it didn't work.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

***UPDATE 1***:
I tried to use this:

```
thirdCol.setCellValueFactory(
      ( TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> p ) ->
{
    List<Person> friends = p.getValue().getFriends();
    String val = friends
             .stream()
             .map( item -> item.getName() )
             .reduce( "", ( acc, item ) -> acc + ", " + item );
    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper( val );
});
```

for my `Issue.class`:

```
thirdCol.setCellValueFactory(
  (TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Issue, List<Issue>> p ) ->
{
    List<Issue> friends = p.getValue().getDependencies();
    String val = friends
             .stream()
             .map( item -> item.getID() )
             .reduce( "", ( acc, item ) -> acc + ", " + item );
    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper( val );
});
```

But I can't compile this because:

*The method setCellValueFactory(Callback>,ObservableValue>>) in the type TableColumn> is not applicable for the arguments ((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures> p) -> {})*

and

*ReadOnlyStringWrapper cannot be resolved to a type*

I've tried to fix this problem by myself but could not find a solution.

Comment: I cannot see any difference between this question and your previous one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126123/how-to-show-a-list-on-table-column-with-few-fields-of-list-items). Just use the answer to that question. What does "it didn't work" mean? You get an exception? You get the wrong result?

Comment: @James_D please have a look at my update.

Comment: Move that comment to the answer to the original question. "I could not implement your answer" is not a reason to post an identical question.