# JavaFX Dynamic TableView from URL json

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create a dynamic tableview that gets its data from a json provided by a webpage. The thing is that whenever the data from the json is out of range (for example the range should be 0.8 - 0.9, but it reads 1.1), the table automatically updates the observablelist with a "RED SQUARE" image. If the data is within range, it shows a "BLUE SQUARE" image. It's like a status indicator so that the user knows if the data is correct or not. I have this code:

```
public ObservableList<PumpSites> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new PumpSites (blue or red square image, "Canduman"),
        new PumpSites (blue or red square image, "Cubacub"),
        new PumpSites (blue or red square image, "Liloan"),
        new PumpSites (blue or red square image, "Talamban"),
        new PumpSites (blue or red square image, "Tisa")
        );

status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PumpSites, String>("status"));
ps.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PumpSites, String>("ps"));
table.setItems(list);

public class PumpSites {
private final SimpleStringProperty status;
private final SimpleStringProperty ps;

public PumpSites(String status, String ps){
    super();
    this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
    this.ps = new SimpleStringProperty(ps);
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status.get();
}

public String getPs() {
    return ps.get();
}

}
```

I have no problem getting data from the json. I am planning to put the dynamic reading of data for the status indicator inside a platform.runlater so that it updates always. How can I show a blue or red square beside the pump site in the table dynamically?

Comment: Are you asking how to periodically refresh the data automatically or how to update the square as the data changes?

Comment: I know how to use platform.runlater, but I don't know how to update the data of the table. I also don't know how to add the square images.

Comment: Your question might be too broad for this site (you seem to have at least 2-3 general questions).

Comment: However, I'd use a `javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService` to periodically pull data from a remote source. You'd could then either completely replace the items in the `TableView` or refresh any already existing data while adding new data and removing no-longer-existing data. To customize the `TableCell`s of a `TableColumn` you would use a `cellFactory`. It might also be beneficial to have a `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty` in `PumpSites` for the validity of the value. Leave the square to the UI (i.e. the `TableCell`s). You should also look into using bindings.

Comment: One can check/read the json data update/availability periodically using a java.util.Timer service. When there is data available/changed refresh the table and show an indicator color in that particular column's cell. Here are links to using a table refresh and creating a table cell with a custom object (like colored cell): [tableview-refresh-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065140/javafx-2-1-tableview-refresh-items) and [tableview-cell-depending-on-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067481/javafx-2-tableview-different-cell-factory-depending-on-the-data-inside-the-cel).

Comment: Also, there are posts on the net with ideas pertaining to your questions: refreshing the tableview, periodically checking something and doing a task, rendering a tableview cell with specific objects. The [javafx.scene.shape package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/package-summary.html) has classes to draw a box or similar shapes.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas and code samples:

**(1)** Rendering a state (yes or no) for a table view's column cell - sample code:

The `DataClass` can have a `boolean` property defined like this:

```
private SimpleBooleanProperty status;
```

The table view's cell can be rendered with the a check box using the status's boolean property values. Here is code how the table view's column may be defined:

```
TableColumn<DataClass, Boolean> statusCol = new TableColumn<>("Status");
statusCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataClass, Boolean>("priority"));
statusCol.setCellFactory(column -> {
    CheckBoxTableCell<DataClass, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
    cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return cell;
});
```

As I have already suggested a colored box (using a  shape class like `Rectangle` from `javafx.scene.shape` package) can be rendered instead of a check box.

**(2)** A `java.util.Timer` and `TimerTask` classes can be used to schedule and run a task periodically. In the main application after the gui is built the timer can be initialized as follows:

```
public class BuildMyAppGui {
    //...
    private void initiateTimer() {

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            long zeroDelay = 0L;
            long period = 60000L; // 60 * 1000 = 1 min

            // The timer runs once the first time
            // and subsequently the scheduled task every one minute
            timer.schedule(new DataChangedTask(), zeroDelay, period);
    }
    //...
}
```

The timer's task class sample code:

```
public class DataChangedTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Code checks if there is a data change and refreshes the table data.
        // This also refreshes the table column with check box -
        // as checked or un-checked depending on the true/false value
        // in the boolean property in DataClass.
    }
}
```

Note the `DataChangedTask` class can have constructors take references to data and access other references as required by the app.

Comment: Can you say briefly how you have resolved (what aspects of the solution post  or suggestions helped)?

Comment: well, the question wasn't very clear - no wonder the answer is not very concrete ;) As to using Timer/Task from java.util package: better not - it'll leave all the burden to update correctly on the fx-app thread on your code (which you should at least mention). Instead, use a Timeline.

Comment: @kleopatra A `Timeline` works great for periodic tasks that need to happen on the FX thread but not when you need periodic tasks to happen on a background thread. OP seems to need to update the data from a remote source which should be retrieved on a background thread. That's why I suggested a `ScheduledService` in my comment; it's basically a single-task `Timer` but handles communication with the FX thread for you (as well as other features).